# How to Disable the Insertion of semicolon in PhpStorm Upon Code Completion

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When writing a CSS property the code-completion feature of PhpStorm automatically inserts a semicolon at the end of the line. I find that annoying when I map grid areas and other long-value properties..

Is there an option to prevent code-completion from auto inserting that semicolon?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible. P.S. As I understand you are talking about something like this (simplified version, assume that the whole content on a single line): `color: dark` and you choose completion (e.g. `darkred`) so it becomes `color: darkred;` Or maybe it's something else? In such case some code sample would be welcome.

Comment: that's exactly what I meant, for example `gta` resolves into `grid-template-areas` that's really cool but the annoying part is that I either have to delete the auto-semicolon or drag it with me on long tour while defining the rest of the areas names

Comment: Create custom Live Template with `gta` as abbreviation that would expand into whatever you want. Right now `gta` suggests `grid-template-areas` property (standard completion search AFAIK as it matches first letters of the target property name parts) and completes it using the same standard way for target language.

Comment: will try that and report..

Comment: So .. have you tried that? Any good?

Comment: sorry about the delay, It worked! thanks :) 
if you're reading this in the future and the trick didn't work for you the first time try changing the sub-option of the CSS Live-Template..

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the Live Template settings (Editor > Live Templates) and open the 'Zen CSS' section.
For each abbreviation there is a template text,
here you can remove the semicolons for the abbreviations you have this issue with.

As far as I know there is no blanket option to remove all semicolons in the live templates build in.
Also, as far as I can see Zen CSS templates are used for regular CSS files but I have no idea if Zen CSS is just regular CSS or a specific language/style.

Comment: FYI: "Zen CSS" is basically standard abbreviations for Emmet (at very least that that's how they are handled/implemented in this IDE -- Live Templates have existed for quite some time before Emmet appeared). They do not cover ALL possible aspects of completion (e.g. values .. or if you already overtyped the abbreviation -- then actual property is offered and not Live Template entry)

Comment: I disabled the entire Zen CSS section and yet the editor was still able to convert the abbreviations I supplied to code/properties.. anyway thank you for your reply